# filter fixed set of elements with default values for non-existing elements using LINQ to xml

Tags: linq-to-xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<root> 
  <level1 name="abc1" type="xyz">   
    <data name="A" count="23" avg="56" />   
    <data name="B" count="67" avg="18" />   
    <data name="C" count="42" avg="23" />   
  </level1> 
  <level1 name="abc2" type="xyz">   
    <data name="B" count="56" avg="29" />   
    <data name="C" count="23" avg="64" />   
    <data name="E" count="78" avg="21" />   
  </level1> 
</root>
```

If the filter list is {A,C,E,F} and want to filter the above document with all the data that have their name attribute's value in the list. If a matching element is not found I would still want to have a data element with that name and all other attributes of that elements set to some default values as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<root> 
  <level1 name="abc1" type="xyz">   
    <data name="A" count="23" avg="56" />   
    <data name="C" count="42" avg="23" />   
    <data name="E" count="0"  avg="0" />   
    <data name="F" count="0"  avg="0" />   
  </level1> 
  <level1 name="abc2" type="xyz">   
    <data name="A" count="0"  avg="0" />   
    <data name="C" count="23" avg="64" />   
    <data name="E" count="78" avg="21" />   
    <data name="F" count="0"  avg="0" />   
  </level1> 
</root>
```

Additionally,  can I also select only the attributes that I want based on a selection criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some C# sample code that produces the output you posted:

```
    XDocument input = XDocument.Load("input.xml");
    XDocument output = new XDocument(
        new XElement(input.Root.Name,
            from level in input.Root.Elements("level1")
            select new XElement("level1",
                level.Attributes(),
                from name in new string[] { "A", "C", "E", "F" }
                let data = level.Elements("data").FirstOrDefault(d => d.Attribute("name").Value == name)
                select (data != null ? data : new XElement("data",
                    new XAttribute("name", name),
                    new XAttribute("count", 0),
                    new XAttribute("avg", 0)
                    )))));
    output.Save("output.xml");
```